# Allow multiple users to change functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, security, users, permissions

I want to make multiple users and allow them to change  procedures,functions and triggers in same DB. There must be user `devel` for    developers and `admin` for admin, both can change developers DB, but admin is not `root`, i.e. he can't change everything, only some databases. 
User `admin` have following permissions:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db_prefix%.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION`

All fine except definers in triggers and procedures. If I set definer in database to `devel@'%'`, i can't edit procedures as `admin`, but `root` user can, of course. 
How can I allow to modify triggers,functions and procedures to multiple users?

**UPD:** I can't edit procedures as `admin` even when definer is `` `%`@`%` ``.

**UPD2:** MySQL version:
`Server version: 5.6.23-ndb-7.4.5-cluster-gpl-log MySQL Cluster Community Server (GPL)`

**UPD 3:** (moved to new question [Allow multiple users to see procedures and functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107318/allow-multiple-users-to-see-procedures-and-functions) )

**UPD 4:** Manuals say that only way to change body of procedure is to drop it and create new. So, I can do it, and my question is incorrect, I want not only change functions/procedures using different users, but also see body (code) of funtions/procedures. That's why I have created new question.

Comment: Did you use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db_prefix%.* TO 'admin'@'%';`. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db_prefix%.* TO 'devel'@'%';`. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`; ?

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work. I can change triggers, but not functions and procedures. I will check later in other version of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) says:

> The ALL or ALL PRIVILEGES privilege specifier is shorthand. It stands
>   for “all privileges available at a given privilege level” (except
>   GRANT OPTION). For example, granting ALL at the global or table level
>   grants all global privileges or all table-level privileges.

Just use:

```
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'admin'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

### Test:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'devel1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'admin'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'devel1'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'devel1'@'%';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for devel1@%                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'devel1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'devel1'@'%'                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'admin'@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin@%                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'admin'@'%'                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I can't write answer in comment because it too long, so I have updated question. Thanks, but as for me it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, it works (I can drop procedures and create new), but I can't see them. Developers  (user ```devel```) can't just get code and edit it if someone will create/update function as ```admin```.