# Allow multiple users to see procedures and functions

Tags: mysql, security, users, permissions

I have `` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test1`.* TO 'admin'@'%' ``, `` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test1`.* TO 'devel'@'%' `` (from `SHOW GRANTS FOR some_user`) and I have created simple procedure as `admin` in `test1`.

And here is what I see:

as `admin`

```
mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| admin@%        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,03 sec)

mysql> SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='test' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA='test1';
+--------------------+
| ROUTINE_DEFINITION |
+--------------------+
| begin
end          |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,04 sec)

mysql> call test();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,03 sec)
```

as `devel`:

```
mysql> select current_user();                                                   +----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| devel@%        |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,03 sec)

mysql> SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='test' AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA='test1';
+--------------------+
| ROUTINE_DEFINITION |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,03 sec)

mysql> call test();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,03 sec)
```

How can I allow multiple users to see code of procedure or function?

Comment: Try granting `EXECUTE` permissions on user `devel`. (`GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE test1.yourprocedure TO 'devel'@'%'`.

Comment: Did you run those commands from above? ^

Comment: MySQL documentation says that ```EXECUTE``` is required to execute stored routines ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute ).
I tried to run commands from above, and I still get ```NULL``` as ```devel```.

Comment: I did the same test as I told you above. I created a SP with `'admin'@'%'` then I did the `SELECTs`. Everything was like you have in your question, but I ran: `GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE test1.yourprocedure TO 'devel'@'%'` and I was able to `SELECT` it on `information_schema`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's my fault, it works. Thanks! 
Can you post your answer as answer, not as comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try granting [`EXECUTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) permissions on user `devel`.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE test1.yourprocedure TO 'devel'@'%'
```

Comment: Is there way to grant execute to all procedures?
```mysql> GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE test1.`%` TO 'devel'@'%';
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION or PROCEDURE % does not exist ```

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT('GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE ',ROUTINE_SCHEMA,'.',ROUTINE_NAME," TO 'devel'@'%';") AS QUERIES FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA='test';` Copy the rows and execute them.

Comment: Thanks! But is there way to do it just once? It seems to me that new procedures will not have appropriate privileges.